# Add "nan" to numpy array 20 times without loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
n = np.array([1.1,2.3,3.4])
for x in range(20):
    n = np.append(n, [np.nan])
```

How can I add `nan` to my `numpy` array 20 times without a loop, only using `numpy`'s tools?

Thanks

Comment: `n = np.append(n, [np.nan]*20)`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
n = np.append(n, np.repeat(np.nan, 20))
```

[Edit]
Ok, it seems that use of `np.repeat` is slower than use of `np.zeros(20) + np.nan` like in [Mr E’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19539488/1517918):

```
In [1]: timeit np.zeros(10000) + np.nan
100000 loops, best of 3: 16.1 µs per loop

In [2]: timeit np.repeat(np.nan, 10000)
10000 loops, best of 3: 70.8 µs per loop
```

But `np.append` is quicker:

```
In [3]: timeit np.append(n, n)
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.56 µs per loop

In [4]: timeit np.hstack((n, n))
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.87 µs per loop
```

So you can combine both approaches:

```
np.append(n, np.zeros(20) + np.nan)
```

This gives:

```
In [42]: timeit np.hstack((n, np.zeros(20) + np.nan))
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.2 µs per loop

In [43]: timeit np.append(n, np.repeat(np.nan, 20))
100000 loops, best of 3: 15.4 µs per loop

In [44]: timeit np.append(n, np.zeros(20) + np.nan)
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.5 µs per loop
```

Comment: np.full(20, np.nan) is an alternative. In my tests it scaled better than np.repeat.

Answer (score 2):

```
n = np.hstack((n, np.zeros(20) + np.nan))
```